# Camouflage but not quite... like zebras

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Camouflage is form and color that blends with the environment and for example make it difficult for a predator to spot a prey...  But what is the correct word when the "camouflage" is *not* made to blend in?

The best example is perhaps the zebra:  Black stripes on white doesn't exactly blend in.  Rather than hiding the zebra in the environment, the purpose seems to be to "break-up" the form of the individual zebra in the flock, so they all sort of floats together - making it difficult for a predator to target any one (particular) among them.  I guess you could say the stripe lets a zebra become "invisible" inside the flock, but...

So is there another word that better describe this than "camouflage"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In WWI the US Navy painted their ships in complex patterns to confuse enemy ships.

> **Dazzle camouflage**, also known as **razzle dazzle** (in the U.S.) or dazzle painting, was a family of ship camouflage used extensively in World War I, and to a lesser extent in World War II and afterwards. ... It consisted of complex patterns of geometric shapes in contrasting colours, interrupting and intersecting each other.
>
> Unlike other forms of camouflage, the intention of dazzle is not to conceal but to make it difficult to estimate a target's range, speed, and heading. ([Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dazzle_camouflage))

While I would not necessarily suggest that you use the terms *razzle dazzle* or *dazzle camouflage* I believe this demonstrates that **camouflage** still applies.

**Edit**

> **Disruptive coloration** (also known as disruptive camouflage or disruptive patterning) is a form of camouflage that works by breaking up the outlines of an animal, soldier or military vehicle with a strongly contrasting pattern

Comment: It's still widely used in the motor industry and [some people even like it](https://www.complex.com/sports/2013/02/25-spy-shot-camos-wed-actually-use-for-paint-jobs/)

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the **zebra and it's camouflage**:  [smithsonian](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/zebra-stripes-might-not-be-camouflage-180957927/)

> If zebra stripes aren’t related to predators, social status or basic
>   survival, why are they there? **For now, the question seems destined to
>   remain one of wildlife’s most beautiful mysteries**.

**Thermoregulation**?  [livescience](https://www.livescience.com/49447-zebras-stripes-cooling.html)
**tsetse flies**?   [UC Davis](http://blogs.ucdavis.edu/egghead/2016/05/25/do-zebras-stripes-confuse-biting-flies/)

> So is there another word that better describe this than "camouflage"?

Unknown! It may not be camouflage at all.

Answer (score 0):

One zebra being hidden among other zebras due to its looks *is* one of the senses of camouflage . . .

However, another word for the concept of "hiding in plain sight" is [**obscurity**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obscurity):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1** : one that is obscure
> **2** : the quality or state of being obscure
>
> [[obscure]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obscure)
>
> **1 c** : not clearly seen or easily distinguished : FAINT • *obscure* markings